# Parameterize the active edge of a register

Tags: verilog

I was wondering if there is an easy way to define the active edge of a module, e.g. a register, in Verilog, so I can define if is positive/negative triggered when is instantiated. For example:

`` Register #(.width(8), .active_edge(`POS_EDGE))  DUT (); ``

This is my attempt, although, I don't know if it is even legal to use a logical operator in the `posedge` variable:

```
module Register #(
    parameter width=8,
    parameter active_edge=1'b1) (
    input      [width-1:0] D,
    input                  clk, rst, we,
    output reg [width-1:0] Q);

    always @(posedge active_edge^~clk, posedge rst) begin
        if (rst)
            Q <= 'b0;
        else
            if (we) Q <= D;
    end

endmodule
```

Comment: Just write it as normal and invert the clock input to switch the active edge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you wrote is legal Verilog, but some synthesis tools might not accept a complex expression for the clock. You can write an intermediate expression and it will get optimized away.

```
module Register #(
    parameter width=8,
    parameter active_edge=1'b1) (
    input      [width-1:0] D,
    input                  clk, rst, we,
    output reg [width-1:0] Q);
    wire local_clk = active_edge ? !clk : clk;
    always @(posedge local_clock, posedge rst) begin
        if (rst)
            Q <= 'b0;
        else
            if (we) Q <= D;
    end

endmodule
```